# Обновление header'a для UITableView

Tags: swift, uikit

у меня есть хедер, который реализован через UIView, добавляю его в хедер таблицы:

`tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView`

собственно вопрос, каким способом я могу перезагрузить хедер у теблицы?
`reloadData` не помогает :(

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод view:

```
setNeedsDisplay()
```

> You can use this method or the setNeedsDisplay(_:) to notify the
>   system that your view’s contents need to be redrawn. This method makes
>   a note of the request and returns immediately. The view is not
>   actually redrawn until the next drawing cycle, at which point all
>   invalidated views are updated.